# css float left and input 100% width

Tags: html, css

I want the input to be `width: 100%;` and be on the right of the image.
Is it possible without using a table? If it is how can I achieve that?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.iconpot.com/icon/thumbnail/geek-avatar.jpg" />
    <input/>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DL8kG/)

Thank you

Comment: Include your code in the question.

Comment: after `100%` width, there will be no place for any other element

Comment: Then it is not possible to do it ? I have to use a fixed width ?

Comment: for the donwvoters maniac. Ok I forgot to add the code in my quesiton at first. But I have edited my question so please stop downvote it is a bit stupid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with calc()

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/DL8kG/19/)**

```
input
{
    width: calc(100% - 130px); /* width of img + extra padding between */
}
```

You could also align the input by styling the img

```
img
{
    vertical-align: middle; /* or top /bottom.. etc */
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. One should note though that not all browsers will support this (but most will): http://caniuse.com/calc

Answer (score 1):

*Demo*: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/DL8kG/9/**

*Idea*:

Wrap your image and input in their own containers. Use `display: table-cell` on containers. Use `vertical-align: middle` to line up. This will allow you to have 100% width.

*Markup*:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="imgWrap">
        <img src="http://www.iconpot.com/icon/thumbnail/geek-avatar.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputWrap">
        <input/>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
div.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.imgWrap {
    display: table-cell;
}
.inputWrap {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 4px;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. I choose @Danield answer as it doesn't need an additional div. But thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Use a floating and overflow trick. Float your image to the left and place your input in a container that will have its overflow hidden. Give the input a width of 100%. The input's container will take up the remainder of the screen (what I assume you mean by 100%):

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.iconpot.com/icon/thumbnail/geek-avatar.jpg" />
    <div class="inp"><input/></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
    float:left;
}
.inp{
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#F00;
}
.inp input{
    width:100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/DL8kG/18/)

Please take note of how your default styles (padding, border..) will affect the total width of the input.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. I choose @Danield answer as it doesn't need an additional div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="img">
    <img src="http://www.iconpot.com/icon/thumbnail/geek-avatar.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="input">
        <input/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#input {

        display:table-cell;
     }
input{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
#img {
    width:130px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DL8kG/30/)

Comment: your input in the provided fiddle is not displaying 100% correct it and I give you an upvote :)

Comment: sorry but your FIDDLE is not working! This is what I want http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/DL8kG/19/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">

<img src="http://www.iconpot.com/icon/thumbnail/geek-avatar.jpg" style="float:left"/>
<div style="float:left">  
 <input /> 
</div>
```